# MS Access not able to open and assign Excel objects

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, excel.application

Excel file won't open in MS Access.

This piece of code was working until a few days ago. Now it's NOT erroring out and it's not creating any Excel objects.

```vb
Dim XL As Object
Set XL = New Excel.Application
XL.workbooks.Open(ourPath)
```

The Object assignment should work (the path is correct, I've checked it multiple times).

Comment: First you do not assign the workbook and you need to make the Excel application [visible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.visible) else it runs in background. Also where is your error handling to catch errors? Please include full code block.

Comment: Today I had a new development, it seems like Filecopy and shell commands are also not executing on this database. and they don't even error out.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using early binding, perhaps you are missing the reference to the Microsoft Excel Object library (*`Tools > References`*), or perhaps this library has been rendered as `MISSING` as a result of opening your database in an earlier version of MS Access.

Nevertheless, to avoid the reliance on references entirely and rule this out as a possible cause, you could try using late binding e.g.:

```
Dim XL As Object
Set XL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
XL.Workbooks.Open(ourPath)
```

Comment: I think that was what original piece of code was. The most surprizing part is the same code is working on a co-worker's machine, which is mind boggling and makes me think some switch got flipped somewhere when as part of some patch, but I can't locate it. And he and I have the refrences checked.

Comment: maybe you have no permissions to access this file on your machine?

Comment: Nope...The excel file and mdb file are in same locations. This code was actually working up until a few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

So what was happening was, the excel files had add-ins that were preventing for excel to be opened properly. The code worked like a charm as soon as those add-ins were disabled.